Pop!_OS slow kernel boot time when ethernet cable not connected
I am running Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS on my laptop, which is based on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
Linux is set up with root partition encryption, with auto-decryption set up during boot since I am only using the laptop at home lately.
During boot, if the ethernet cable is not connected, I am getting around a minute delay waiting for DHCP to resolve before eventually timing out, and allowing the boot process to continue.
This can be seen as a high kernel boot time in systemd-analyze:
Startup finished in 2.832s (firmware) + 605ms (loader) + 1min 9.552s (kernel) + 11.778s (userspace) = 1min 24.769s 
graphical.target reached after 11.754s in userspace

When the ethernet cable is connected, I assume DHCP is quickly assigning an ip to the laptop, shaving off around a minute from the boot process.
The output of ethtool for the wired network adaptor is:
sudo ethtool -i enp3s0f1
driver: r8169
version: 6.9.3-76060903-generic
firmware-version: rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:03:00.1
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no

What is the best way to decrease the timeout value for waiting for DHCP to assign an ip?

Please run sudo ethtool -i <network adapter name> to identify the driver used by your wired network adapter. For example, if the wired NIC is named eno1, please run sudo ethtool -i eno1 and add the output to your question. Apparently Network manager and/or the DHCP client cannot see the link state of the wired NIC and so won't know the cable is not connected.

@telcoM Added ethtool output to the question. Thank you
